# Indian international student in Canada applying for a US visit visa

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, b1-b2-visas

I came to Canada on December 26, 2017 as a student. I am done with my first semester and currently have a semester break until September. I'm planning to apply for a US visit visa (B1/B2) to visit my friends for 10 days.

I heard from a few people that I need to wait for at least 6 months from my arrival date in Canada to apply for a B1/B2 visa, which is end of June. Is it mandatory to wait 6 months after arrival to apply for a B1/B2 visa, or can I apply for it even now? Please help.

Comment: There is no such waiting period. You can apply whenever you wish.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Can you please put that into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such restriction; you can apply at any time for a [nonimmigrant visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html) to come to the US as temporary visitor, and can do so though any of the [US Consulates in Canada](https://ca.usembassy.gov/embassy-consulates/).

The [wait times](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html) vary and some are lengthy: in Montreal, it currently takes 56 days; Toronto 84 days; Vancouver 17 days; Calgary 10 days; Ottawa 30; Quebec 10; Halifax, 36. ait time also does not include the time required to return the passport to applicants, by either courier services or the local mail system.